# UDF Helloworld sample in c++

Tags: c++, mysql

I have written a sample user defined function (helloworld in c++):

```
 extern "C"
 char * hello(UDF_INIT * initid, UDF_ARGS * args,
     char * result, unsigned long * length,
     char * is_null, char * error) {

     strcpy(result, "Hello");
     strcat(result, " ");
     strcat(result, args -> args[0]);
     * length = strlen(result);

     return result;
 }

 extern "C"
 bool hello_init(UDF_INIT * initid, UDF_ARGS * args, char * message) {
     if (args -> arg_count != 1) {
         strcpy(message, "hello requires exactly one string argument");
         return 1;
     }
     if (args -> arg_type[0] != STRING_RESULT) {
         strcpy(message, "hello requires exactly one string argument");
         return 1;
     }

     initid -> max_length = args -> lengths[0] + strlen("hello ");
     return 0; /* true */
 }

 extern "C"
 void hello_deinit(UDF_INIT * initid) {
     return;
 }
```

when I create the function in sql command using :

```
CREATE FUNCTION remote returns string  SONAME 'Hello.so';
```

and run the command :

```
mysql> select hello ('test');
      +--------------------------------+
      | hello ('test')                 |
      +--------------------------------+
      | 0x48656C6C6F2074657374         |
      +--------------------------------+
      1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

the result is shown in Hex format, does any one know why and how can I show the result in varchar not hex?

Comment: Why `extern "C"` all over the place??

Comment: because I want to write a C code and create .so file in order to use it for creating udf